# Is it more common, or best practice, to design several web pages to fill out user profile data or one page divided into sections?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, design-patterns

I notice that a site like LinkedIn feels overwhelming and clumsy to me when I'm trying to update my profile. I would guess that LinkedIn would hire some of the best developers in the world, yet it feels slow and clunky at times.

Facebook seems downright cryptic at times. Figuring out Google's myriad settings seems somewhat 'user unfriendly' as well. Twitter's and GitHub's profiles seem much more user friendly and functional for my purposes. Dribbble and Instagram seem thankfully simple.

Is it just me? Does it need to be so cumbersome and overdone?

I'm just wondering if this is mostly my experience, if there are best practices around this idea, if the LinkedIn website has 'issues' from the point of view of design experts, and if there are examples of very well done 'profile-type' websites anyone could point me to.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your point but in my observation, LinkedIn is more focused for professionals, and they know that in order for a user to be effective professional in the network, they have to invest time putting in details of your self, your previous work, what you are doing and how you can help your prospects in their business. So the answer to your question is, it always depends on your users and goal as a business.

Ex.
If you want to guide your users to have more focused for each questions because they are quite complicated
- Better to use step by step form

If your goal is to convert prospect visitors into registered users right away, do something like Facebook/Twitter
- they only ask for fewer details to register and give other details after logging in